# google recaptcha to send email

Tags: javascript, html, captcha, forms

I'm looking to use google's recaptcha to add to my website. The html form simply needs call the `MAILTO` action if the recaptcha returns true to the send button. This is simplified code in the `<head>` and `<body>`.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : 'my key'
        });
      };
    </script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="MAILTO:my.email@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        Name<br><input type="text"><br><br>
        E-mail<br><input type="text"><br><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey"></div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
    </script>
</body>
```

The one problem is that I'm new to javascript so following [google's javascript API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) properly has been difficult. The `send` button can be pressed at any time.

In short what I'd like to learn is:

1. How to only allow the send button to function when google's captcha returns true.
2. How to center the captcha in css.

Comment: What do you want that for? Spambots dont "visit" your site, they crawl it. They will find your email in your sourcecode. Using googlerecaptcha to hide it will not work. You need to check the google response on your backend, and if positive sending the email address back to the client

Comment: Huh, I was unaware of that fact. So essentially would I need to POST the form and access the data via php?

Comment: To make it as spamsecure as possible yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var verifyCallback = function(response) {
//called when success
 document.all.body.hide.style.display="block";
};
var onloadCallback = function(){
grecaptcha.render('verify', {
'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
'callback' : verifyCallback,
'theme' : 'dark'
});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="verify"></div>
<form>
<button type="submit" id="hide">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer>
</script>
<style>#hide{display:none;}</style> </body></html>
```

Comment: Hi Jonas. Your code doesn't seem to generate a response to show the submit button upon rendering the google verify call. Any help would be great

Comment: Any errors (look at the console) and what exactly does not work?

Comment: So I think your code does the opposite of what I'm looking for. I would like the submit button to appear, after google's recaptcha returns True.

Comment: Thats what it does. Wheres the problem??

Comment: The submit button is never hidden.

Comment: Thats what #hide{display:none;} us for